# How to pad the pages in a murder mystery

Tags: narrative, process, pacing, mystery

I have arrived at a plot point that I would rather be later. If one were to say that a page is 250 words, then the murderer has scapegoated someone else at page 8. As far as I can recall, Agatha Christie, for example, has such things not at the beginning, but after a significant amount of time. How can I rescue my story in terms of length from webnovel syndrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have arrived at...

That sounds as if you have been discovery writing. Haven't you outlined your novel beforehand?

Discovery writing works well if you have a lot of experience or write some meandering genre like a quest fantasy, but murder mysteries need to be planned painstakingly in advance.

Unlike in other genres in a murder mystery the end is always firm and certain before you begin working on the book. You, the author, know who dunnit. And to reveal that slowly and in a thrilling and suspenseful manner, you need to carefully plan when to reveal which clue. In a story like a murder mystery where the end is already set, there is a tendency in discovery writing that you involuntarily try to get there. And then exactly what you experienced happens: You reveal clues to early.

**I would never "pad" a story.** The result will be boring for the readers. Instead,

### Start fresh.

Put away your current draft and create a (new) outline. Then write the story again.